How can I extract the string from a span tag with attribute?
I'm trying to scrape the text from this table.
<tbody>
    <tr class="">
        <td class="a"><span data-v-4a598ac2="">Text1</span></td>
        <td class="b"><span data-v-4a598ac2="">Text2</span></td>
        <td class="c"><span data-v-77cd9800="" data-v-4a598ac2="">Text3</span></td>
        <td class="b"><span data-v-4a598ac2="">Text4</span></td>
        <td class="b"><span data-v-4a598ac2="">Text5</span></td>
        <td class="b"><span data-v-4a598ac2="">Text6</span></td>
    </tr>
    ...
</tbody>

After the "..." there are more lines that I want to scrape.
How can I scrape the Text1, Text2, ..., Text6 using the BeautifulSoup from Python?
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://..."
headers = {
        'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36"
        }
site = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('span', attrs='data-v-4a598ac2'))

But the result that I get is "None" and not the text.
I tried this:
print(soup.find('span', attrs='data-v-4a598ac2').string)

but I get this error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
Or using the get_text but i get this error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

The website is probably using Javascript. and, requests doesn't support that. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/8049520/12349734
If you [edit] your question to include the link, we can take a look.

Your code seems correct except find method returns only the first matching element. If you want to get all matching elements, you should use find_all method instead, but since you are describing that you received None as output that would mean the above response <span data-v-4a598ac2=""> is not present in it. You should try to verify if it first then edit your question and ask again.

if the <td> tags only contain one span, you can use td.text, or td.span.text. are there spans you want to exclude? if you share the site link, it would be easier to help.

Do you see the elements you're trying to scrape when you use View Source? If not, they're being added dynamically and you'll need to use Selenium WebDriver to scrape it.

When using BeautifulSoup, you should pass a dictionary to the attrs parameter to specify attributes and their values. Probably vue.js would have been used to generate dynamic attributes for which requests.get can't be used.
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

# Find the element with the specific data attribute
element = soup.find('span', {'data-v-4a598ac2': True})

# Extract the text from the element
if element:
    text = element.get_text()
    print(text)  # Output: Text1


It's not scprapping the Text1. The result that I get is None.

Pl share the site link. Btw, I've edited one line into element = soup.find('span', {'data-v-4a598ac2': True})

Sadly, I cant share with you because it's from a portal and it's required and login acceess

Did you try my edited code?
